# What are the 2-generated subgroups of the special linear group $SL(2, q)$ over a finite field?

Tags: gr.group-theory, matrices, finite-groups

What is the subgroup structure of the subgroups $\langle a, b\rangle$ where $a, b \in SL(2, q)$?

Comment: I recall reading somewhere (but I forgot where and maybe I misremembered) that if you pick $a, b$ unifomly at random then the probability of $\langle a, b \rangle$ being the whole group tends to 1 as $q$ goes to infinity. Does anyone know if this is true (or what the correct version of this statement is)?

Comment: Yes, more generally if you pick two elements of a random finite (quasi-)simple group $G$ then the probability that they generate $G$ tends to $1$ as $|G|$ tends to $\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

The complete subgroup structure of ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ has been well understood for many years, probably dating back as far as L.E. Dickson, so it is only a matter of deciding which subgroups are $2$-generated. If $q = p^{m}$ for some prime $p$ and positive integer $m$, then ${\rm SL}(2,p^{n})$ is always a $2$-generator subgroup of ${\rm SL}(2,p^{m})$ when $n$ is a divisor of $m$ (later edit in view of Derek Holt's comment:in fact, it is sometimes possible to extend ${\rm SL}(2,p^{n})$ by a diagonal automorphism of order $2$). When ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ has  order divisible by $120$, ${\rm SL}(2,5)$ will occur as a $2$-generator subgroup of ${\rm SL}(2,q)$. All other possible subgroups of ${\rm SL}(2,q)$  are solvable of very restricted structure.

Comment: In fact if $m/n$ is even and $q$ is odd, then the extension ${\rm SL}(2,p^n).2$ of ${\rm SL}(2,p^n)$ by a diagonal automorphism is a $2$-generator subgroup of ${\rm SL}((2,p^m)$.

Comment: Interesting. Could you recommend a reference for this? Thank you!

Comment: There are some references recommended in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118021 (this is for ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$, but it's not very different).

Comment: @DerekHolt :Thanks Derek, I wold have missed that. Presumably the outer automorphism of order $2$ is realised by an element of order 4?

Comment: Yes, the diagonal matrix $[w,w^{−1}]$ where $w$ squares into a primitive element of ${\mathbb F}_{p^n}$ has order $2(q−1)$ and induces a diagonal outer automorphism of ${\rm SL}(2,p^n)$. Multiplying that by $\left(\begin{array}{rr}0&1\\−1&0\end{array}\right)$ gives an element of order 4 that induces an outer automorphism of order $2$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard question. As an example, here is [a paper](http://www2.math.ou.edu/~dmccullough/research/pdffiles/exceptional.pdf) on when such subgroups are isomorphic to some standard permutation groups (D. McCullough, 2005).

Comment: But it's not really a hard question!